# NPM keeps failing when trying to install ZeroRPC

Tags: npm, npm-install, zeromq, failed-installation, zerorpc

Everytime I run `npm install zerorpc` I get this:

```
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\zeromq
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/prebuild-install.js || (node scripts/preinstall.js && node-gyp rebuild)
npm ERR! Downloading libzmq for Windows
npm ERR! Download finished
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.2 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - will only use this version
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32228.343) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32228.343) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1831) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\@npmcli\\run-script\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\zeromq
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-10T12_12_25_422Z-debug-0.log
```

Here's the full log on pastebin if you need it: https://pastebin.com/XBQwUPDX

I've got Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019

I've got the build tools

Desktop development with C++ installed

Updated node-gyp

Haven't been able to install Zeromq, gives the same error

Comment: Hi Obliveater95, did you figure this problem out? I'm currently experiencing the same problem. I'm going to try installation with Python 2.7 today.